# Listview does not populate first time

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating a `ListView` by populating an `ArrayList` in open activity and opening it as a `ListView` in another activity.

When I open the second activity My `ListView` only populates when I open the activity, the `Get_Issue` activity opens blank. When I go back and re-enter the activity (Calling the Get_Issue.class for the second time). Then the `ListView`is populated.

I guess the screen is loading before the listView is created/populated?

How can I improve my code so that the listView is populate the first time I call the `Get_Issue` activity. I do not want to open an empty activity.

```
class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    DatabaseReference databaseIssue;
    public static List<Issue> issueList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Issue> getIssueList() {
        return issueList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
        databaseIssue  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Issue");
    }

    private void getTheData(){
        databaseIssue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                issueList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Issue getData = postSnapshot.getValue(Issue.class);
                    issueList.add(getData);}}
        });
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == getData){
            getTheData();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Get_Issue.class));
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter class

```
public class Get_Issue extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void populateListView() {
        List<Issue> issues = ProfileActivity.getIssueList();

        ArrayAdapter<Issue> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                R.layout.da_item,
                issues);

        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.issue_list);
        populateListView();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a chance that `getTheData()` hasn't finished by the time `populateListView()` is ready in your `Get_Issue` activity.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, is there anyway to fix this so that `populateListView()` does not finish until the `getTheData()` has?